# HTML Agility Pack - Select nodes after specific node

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, html-agility-pack

I asked the question [in a codeplex discussion](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=78043) but I hope to get a quicker answer here at stackoverflow.

So, I use HTML Agility Pack for HTML parsing in C#.
I have the following html structure:

```
<body>
   <p class="paragraph">text</p>
   <p class="paragraph">text</p>
   <p class="specific">text</p>
   <p class="paragraph">text</p>
   <p class="paragraph">text</p>
</body>
```

And I need to get all p elements with class "paragraph" that exist after the p element with class "specific".

Is there a way to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

using .Class as in Mark's example (if that doesnt exist, substitute whatever is appropriate)

Use [SkipWhile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549075.aspx)

e.g. in [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net) you get `5,6,7` from:

```
int[] a = { 6, 5, 6 ,7 };
a.SkipWhile(x=>x!=6).Skip(1).Dump();
```

So depending on the type SelectNodes returns, either:

```
.SelectNodes( "/p" ).SkipWhile( p => p.Class != "specific" ).Skip(1)
```

or

```
.SelectNodes( "/p" ).Cast<XX>().SkipWhile( p => p.Class != "specific" ).Skip(1)
```

(or, ugly version)

```
.SelectNodes( "/p" ).SkipWhile( p => ((XX)p).Class != "specific" ).Skip(1)
```

(or in some cases - not if your expression is already filtering appropriately)

```
.SelectNodes( "/p" ).OfType<XX>().SkipWhile( p => p.Class != "specific" ).Skip(1)
```

EDIT: I'd probably create an extension method:

```
static class HapExtensions
{
    public IEnumerable<T> SkipUntilAfter( this IEnumerable<T> sequence, Predicate<T> predicate) {
        return sequence.SkipWhile( predicate).Skip(1);
       }
}
```

Anyone care to search up prior art for this? Any good name suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
bool latterDayParagraphs = false;
List<DocumentNode> nodes = new List<DocumentNode>();
foreach(var pElement in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("/p"))
{
   if(pElement.Class != "paragraph") 
   {
      latterDayParagraphs = true;
      continue;
   }
   if(latterDayParagraphs)
   {
      nodes.Add(pElement);
   }
}
```

Comment: I guess you just looked over the question, not actually read it. :) I parse the HTML in C# with HTML Agility Pack, and I need to select only the p tags with class="paragraph" that are after the p tag with class="specific".

Comment: Sorry about that, hope this answer is more useful (you'll need a reference to System.Linq). :)

Comment: That will select ALL the p tags with "paragraph" class. I need only the ones AFTER the p tag with class="specific".

Comment: Sorry it is early here, hope that helps, it's hard to think of a more elegant way.

Comment: No problem, mate, I appreciate you're trying to help. 
This solution crossed my mind but I am still hoping that I don't have to use it. Maybe a more elegant one will pop up. If not, I will mark you answer.